# Find similar words individually after obtaining words which started with capital inside the paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word, duplicates, find, highlight

I can find the words starting with a capital letter using the following command

```
     Selection.Find.Text = "<([A-Z][0-9A-Z\a-z]{1,15})>"
```

What exactly I'm struggling with is to take each word one by one and finding similar words in the document first one word and find all duplicates and next second word. I hope I had expressed what I'm trying to create.
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You do not understand how to use Find/Replace in Word.  Please do some research in this area, update your code appropriately and then come back and ask a new question if you are still having problems

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is poorly worded and, hence, it is difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve. Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
Dim StrFnd As String, i As Long
StrFnd = "|"
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "<[A-Z][A-Za-z]@>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    If InStr(StrFnd, "|" & .Text & "|") = 0 Then StrFnd = StrFnd & .Text & "|"
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
  With .Find
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
    For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrFnd, "|"))
      .Text = Split(StrFnd, "|")(i)
      .Replacement.Text = "^&"
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```